# Swift Table View taking too much time to load JSON data

Tags: ios, swift

There are total number of 114 data to fetch from web through API request. But it takes 10-15 seconds to load the data. I tried DispatchQueue() but found no improvement. ViewDidLoad and JSON parse code:

```
func parseJSON()  {
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.alquran.cloud/v1/quran/ar.alafasy")
    guard url != nil else{
        print("URL Founr Nill")
        return
    }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil && data != nil{
            do{
                let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Surah.self, from: data!)
                self.surahName = response.data.surahs
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
                }
            }catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }.resume() 
}
```

Table View code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:QuranAudioCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! QuranAudioCell
    let surah = surahName[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameLbl.text = surah.englishName
    cell.arabicNameLbl.text = surah.name
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You are making a network request. Are you sure it's not the network request that's taking that long (rather than the actual UI update)?

Comment: actually i am not sure

Comment: Add a print on `if error == nil && data != nil{`, check "the date" time it takes. Could be there... If you have a bad connection, or the server is slow, that's normal, no?

Comment: if error == nil && data != nil{
print("Total data: \(data!)") . yes it takes much time

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code above the only thing that can be sooo slow is the networr request you are making.

Your `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0) {` in viewDidLoad is rather pointless TBH

The only way to speed this up at this point is debugging the network call.

- Is your Connection generally slow? (Try to ping google.com in terminal)
- Is your Connection to the specific server slow? (Try to ping the host in terminal)
- Is your Server slow to respond (Try to open it in Webbrowser or use curl in terminal to get the JSON

Comment: ping: 64 bytes from 172.67.177.176: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=103.488 ms